# I'm trying to outline my data with a triangle on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a triangle to a ggplot but I can't succeed. Here is an example of what I want using R basic plot function :

```
x <- c(350, 2750, 1550)
y <- c(100,100,2500)

plot(rangem_brk$Range~rangem_brk$Mid,ylim=c(100,2750),xlim=c(350,2750))
polygon(x, y)
```

But I guess there is also a solution with ggplot . To outline my data I tried this :

```
p<-
rangem_brk%>%
ggplot()+
geom_point(aes(x=Mid,y=Range))+
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(100,2000,by=200))+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(350,2750,by=200))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family='', face='bold', colour='black', size=15),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(family='', face='bold', colour='black', size=13),
        axis.text.x= element_text(face="bold",angle=45,size=14),
        axis.text.y= element_text(face="bold",size=14),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=15, face="bold"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=15, face="bold"))

triangle<-data.frame(poly_y=y,poly_x=x)
p+geom_polygon(aes(data=triangle,x=poly_x,y=poly_y,alpha=.75))
```

What is wrong with my way of doing it ?

You can find a reproductible code below :

```
structure(list(Range = c(100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 100, 400, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 400, 600, 400, 100, 100, 800, 800, 
800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 100, 800, 1000, 1000, 200, 200, 200, 
1000, 600, 1000, 1000, 1000, 600, 200, 100, 800, 100, 400, 100, 
100, 800, 100, 100, 100, 100, 1200, 1200, 800, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 1200, 400, 800, 1200, 100, 800, 100, 100, 1000, 600, 200, 
200, 200, 200, 1000, 1400, 200, 200, 100, 100, 1200, 100, 100, 
400, 100, 100, 100, 400, 100, 100, 1200, 400, 800, 100, 100, 
400, 400, 400, 100, 100, 100, 400, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 1600, 
100, 100, 100, 800, 1800, 1000, 600, 600, 1800, 200, 1000, 200, 
200, 600, 200, 1400, 1800, 200, 200, 200, 1800, 1000, 200, 200, 
1200, 100, 100, 100, 800, 1200, 100, 400, 100, 100, 400, 800, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
800, 800, 800, 100, 100, 800, 400, 1400, 600, 1000, 1800, 600, 
200, 1400, 1800, 1800, 1400, 1000, 600, 1000, 200, 1000, 200, 
200, 200, 1000, 1000, 600, 100, 1200, 1600, 100, 400, 100, 1200, 
100, 100, 1600, 400, 100, 100, 800, 1600, 400, 100, 100, 100, 
600, 1400, 1400, 1000, 1400, 200, 800, 100, 100, 400, 100, 100, 
100, 1200, 400, 400, 400, 100, 200, 200, 1000, 200, 1800, 1800, 
1000, 200, 100, 100, 400, 100, 100, 400, 1600, 1400, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 400, 200, 200, 100), Mid = c(350, 350, 350, 
450, 450, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 650, 
750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 850, 
850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 950, 950, 
950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 
950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 1050, 
1050, 1050, 1050, 1050, 1050, 1050, 1050, 1050, 1050, 1150, 1150, 
1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 
1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 
1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1150, 1250, 
1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 
1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1350, 1350, 1350, 
1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 
1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 
1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1350, 1450, 1450, 1450, 1450, 
1450, 1450, 1450, 1450, 1450, 1450, 1450, 1450, 1450, 1450, 1450, 
1450, 1450, 1450, 1450, 1450, 1450, 1550, 1550, 1550, 1550, 1550, 
1550, 1550, 1550, 1550, 1550, 1550, 1550, 1550, 1550, 1550, 1550, 
1550, 1550, 1550, 1650, 1650, 1650, 1650, 1650, 1650, 1750, 1750, 
1750, 1750, 1750, 1750, 1750, 1750, 1750, 1750, 1750, 1750, 1850, 
1850, 1850, 1850, 1850, 1850, 1850, 1850, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 
1950, 1950, 1950, 2050, 2150, 2150, 2350, 2550, 2550, 2550, 2550, 
2650, 2650, 2750)), row.names = c(NA, -246L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, you have too much stuff in your `aes()` for `geom_polygon()`, which should only include the stuff that changes in your data frame: `x=` and `y=`.  Unless you're mapping `alpha=` to something in your data frame, leave it out because it's a constant.  The same goes for `data=`, which should always be outside `aes()`.  Here's something that works using your datasets:

```
p <- ggplot(rangem_brk, aes(x=Mid, y=Range)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_point()

p + geom_polygon(data=triangle, aes(x=poly_x, y=poly_y), alpha=0.1, color='black')
```

[image]